# Outer Join The Rails 3 Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have 3 models like :

```
location, user, discovered_location(location_id,user_id)
```

I think i need an outer join in order to get all locations, as well as include the discovered_location model, if that location has been discovered by the user.

I would need something like `{location1, location2, location3:includes discovered_location, location4 ..}`

Is there a Rails 3 way to do that ? If not, what is the best way ?

EDIT

I want to get the locations specified above, for a certain user. To better illustrate, it should be :

user `{location1, location2, location3:includes discovered_location, location4 ..}`

(A user has many discovered locations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that the user id in your discovered_locations table is either equal to the id of the user in question, or is null.  This is easily accomplished with the [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) gem.  Given the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discovered_locations
  has_many :locations, :through => :discovered_locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discovered_locations
  has_many :users, :through => :discovered_locations
end

class DiscoveredLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Insert some dummy data, then execute a statement such as this:

```
Location.includes(:discovered_locations).where(
  {:discovered_locations => {:user_id => User.first.id}} | 
  {:discovered_locations => {:user_id => nil}}
).each do |loc|
  puts "#{loc.name} #{loc.discovered_locations.empty? ? 'not visited' : 'visited'}"
end
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do an outer join in Rails only by using an SQL literal in the `joins` method:

```
joins("OUTER JOIN table2 on table2.column = table1.column")
```

Comment: AR will perform an OUTER JOIN if you use the `includes` method and also use a condition on an included table.

Comment: thanx, this seems to be working like BossLocation.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN discovered_locations ON discovered_locations.boss_location_id = boss_locations.id")

Comment: Dave, i couldn't manage to find the right combination of includes/joins to get an outer join like this this mysql : SELECT `boss_locations`.*, `discovered_locations`.* FROM `boss_locations` LEFT OUTER JOIN discovered_locations ON discovered_locations.boss_location_id = boss_locations.id;

Comment: hmm, actually no, i think i do it wrong. I would want to get all locations of a certain user, along with the discovered.

Comment: Ryan, how can i get this join to work for a certain user ? I currently have "BossLocation.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN discovered_locations ON discovered_locations.boss_location_id = boss_locations.id")", but this does not correlate with a specific user_id.

Comment: i also edited my question to better illustrate what i'm searching for

Comment: You would need to specify `where("user_id = ? OR user_id IS NULL", @user_id)` to limit this to a particular user.  This will probably work for you, but isn't as clean as using ruby.  Plus, using SQL like this can bite you in unexpected ways...so best not to go that road unless you have to (which you don't).  If you look at my answer, sub out `User.first.id` with the user id that you're looking for and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

`joins` makes an inner join, `includes` makes an outer join.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations